# facebook profile is null for the first time

Tags: android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity, android-facebook

The function onCurrentProfileChanged doesnt get called everytime I logout and login, but if I remove the profiletracker, the profile comes as null for the first time login.How do i resolve the issue?. I have pasted the code below.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    SharedPreferenceManager.setApplicationContext(getApplicationContext());
    onregister();
    SharedPreferenceManager.setPreference("notificationcount", 0);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
            new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(final LoginResult loginResult) {
                    profileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
                        @Override
                        protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile oldProfile, Profile currentProfile) {
                            Profile.setCurrentProfile(currentProfile);
                            profileTracker.stopTracking();
                            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                                    AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                                    new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onCompleted(
                                                JSONObject jsonObject,
                                                GraphResponse response) {
                                            try {
                                                dismissProgressDialog();
                                                final Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
                                                SharedPreferenceManager.setPreference("id", profile.getId());
                                                email = jsonObject.getString("email");
                                                gender = jsonObject.getString("gender");
                                                if (mAuthTask == null) {
                                                    mAuthTask = new UserLoginTask(email, "", profile.getName(), "facebook", profile.getId(), AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getToken(), gender, getRegistrationId(getApplicationContext()));
                                                    //Log.v("token", loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken());
                                                    mAuthTask.execute((Void) null);
                                                }

                                            } catch (JSONException exe) {

                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                            parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,link,email,gender");
                            request.setParameters(parameters);
                            request.executeAsync();
                        }
                    };
                    profileTracker.startTracking();
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    dismissProgressDialog();
                    LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                    dismissProgressDialog();
                    LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
                }
            });
```

Comment: Can you please tell me why you are using the Profile. ??

Answer (score 0):

Have you added this line in your code

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("public_profile,email"));
```

before call registerCallback?